# Django code base tests fail in virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I'm using Django 1.3.1, python 2.7.6 on Ubuntu 14.04, virtualenv  13.1.2 and virtualenvwrapper 4.7.1.

I've been trying to get the Django unit tests (not my own tests, the tests for Django functionality itself) to run clean in preparation for an upgrade from Django 1.3.1 to the current version but they consistently fail in a virtualenv. They run fine when I am not in a virtualenv. I've tried:

1. Creating a new project and running the tests, they fail--but at least I know it doesn't have to do with my project.
2. Creating a new virtualenv and installing the bare minimum (e.g. just Django) and testing this against the bare project, they fail.
3. Creating a new project and adding everything I have on my machine, even that fails.

All/most the test failures have to do with the module `django.contrib.auth.tests.forms` with several of them shown below:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_success (django.contrib.auth.tests.forms.AuthenticationFormTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jasonwong/.virtualenvs/testagain/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/tests/forms.py", line 112, in test_success
    self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
AssertionError: False is not true

======================================================================
FAIL: test_password_change_fails_with_invalid_old_password (django.contrib.auth.tests.views.ChangePasswordTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jasonwong/.virtualenvs/testagain/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/tests/views.py", line 162, in test_password_change_fails_with_invalid_old_password
    self.login()
  File "/home/jasonwong/.virtualenvs/testagain/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/tests/views.py", line 43, in login
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
AssertionError: 200 != 302

======================================================================
FAIL: test_password_change_fails_with_mismatched_passwords (django.contrib.auth.tests.views.ChangePasswordTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jasonwong/.virtualenvs/testagain/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/tests/views.py", line 173, in test_password_change_fails_with_mismatched_passwords
    self.login()
  File "/home/jasonwong/.virtualenvs/testagain/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/tests/views.py", line 43, in login
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
AssertionError: 200 != 302
```

I'm certain that it is a configuration error but I have no idea where to look at this point.

Comment: since you are about to ditch django 1.3 there isn't a need to test that code base.

Comment: @e4c5 That's true. But I just tried with Django=1.4 and I encounter similar problems in the bare project...

Comment: Don't forget that 1.3 and 1.4 have been unmaintained for ages. Maybe these are known issues that you are running into. Anyway testing the django code base is an utter waste of time (unless you are one of the django core developers, or you have run into an inexplicable bug )

Comment: @e4c5 I guess that's true...thanks for your help :).

Comment: @ishikun not sure how your running in the virtual environment but I ran into a problem where ./manage.py tests was means of calling python.  I don't believe it picks the right python directory in that case.  try running it with: python manage.py tests